# Why is finalizer called on object

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, finalizer

Here is example program that exhibits surprising finalization behavior:

```
class Something
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Doing something");
    }
    ~Something()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Called finalizer");
    }
}

namespace TestGC
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           var s = new Something();
           s.DoSomething();
           GC.Collect();
           //GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
           s.DoSomething();
           Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

If I run the program, what gets printed is:

```
Doing something
Doing something
Called finalizer
```

This appears as expected. Because there is a reference to s after the call to `GC.Collect()`, s is not a garbage.

Now remove comments from the line   `//GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();`
build and run the program again.

I would expect nothing to change in the output. This because I read that **if object is found to be a garbage and it has a finalizer, it will be put on finalizer queue**. Since object is not a garbage, then is seems logical that it should not be put on finalizer queue. Thus the line commented out should do nothing.

However, the output of the program is:

```
Doing something
Called finalizer
Doing something
```

Can somebody help my understanding of why finalizer gets called?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can't reproduce the problem on my laptop, but your `DoSomething` method doesn't use any fields within the object. That means that the object can be finalized *even while `DoSomething` is running*.

If you change your code to:

```
class Something
{
    int x = 10;

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        x++;
        Console.WriteLine("Doing something");
        Console.WriteLine("x = {0}", x);
    }
    ~Something()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Called finalizer");
    }
}
```

... then I suspect you will *always* see `DoingSomething` printed twice before "Called finalizer" - although the final "x = 12" may be printed after "Called finalizer".

Basically, finalization can be somewhat surprising - I *very* rarely find myself using it, and would encourage you to avoid finalizers wherever possible.

Comment: Indeed, that made the difference. Thanks. The real life example is more involved C++/CLI program where I need finalizer.

Comment: @Tony: How convinced are you that you *really* need the finalizer? See http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:pS2g2LI5wMAJ:joeduffyblog.com/2005/12/27/never-write-a-finalizer-again-well-almost-never/+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=uk for example.

Answer (score 7):

Jon's answer is of course correct. I would add to it that the C# specification calls out that the compiler and runtime are *allowed* to (but not *required* to) notice that the reference contained in a local variable is never again dereferenced, and at that point the garbage collector is allowed to treat the object as dead if the local is the last living reference. Therefore the object can be collected and the finalizer run even though there appears to be a reference in a living local variable.  (And similarly the compiler and runtime are allowed to make locals live *longer* if they so choose.)

Given this fact you can end up in bizarre situations. For example, it is possible for a finalizer to be executing on the finalizer thread *while the object's constructor is running on a user thread*. If the runtime can determine that "this" is never dereferenced again then the object can be treated as dead the moment the constructor is done mutating fields of "this". If the constructor then does additional work -- say, mutating global state -- then that work can be done as the finalizer is running.

This is just yet another reason why writing a correct finalizer is so difficult that you probably should not do so. In a finalizer **[everything you know is wrong](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fVDzuT0fXro)**. Everything you're referring to could be dead, you're on a different thread, the object might not be fully constructed, possibly none of your program invariants are actually maintained.

Comment: To make things even worse, it's possible for an object to become eligible for immediate finalization when no strong rooted references to it exist, but for strong rooted references to be re-established, and for other code to start using the object, before the finalizer runs.  Even of objects don't resurrect themselves, it's very difficult for an object to guard against being resurrected by something else.

Answer (score 3):

Your `DoSomething()` is so trivial that it's likely to get inlined. After it's been inlined, there's nothing that still has a reference to the object, so there's nothing preventing it from being garbage collected.

[`GC.KeepAlive()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.gc.keepalive%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is designed specifically for this scenario. It can be used if you want to prevent an object from being garbage collected. It does nothing, but the garbage collector doesn't know that. Call `GC.KeepAlive(s);` at the end of `Main` to prevent it from being finalised earlier.