# Dispose works fine, but not on terminating

Tags: c#, gdi+

I have a class that implements `IDisposable`, because it uses image resources (`Bitmap` class) from GDI+. I use it for wrapping all that gimmicky `LockBits`/`UnlockBits`. And it works fine, be it when I call `Dispose()` or with the `using` statement.

However, if I leave the program to terminate without disposing, I get a `System.AccessViolationException`. Intuitively, I think the GC would call the `Dispose` the same way I do, and the object would gracefully release the resources, but that's not what happening. Why?

---

Here's the `IDisposable` code:

```
private bool _disposing = false;

~QuickBitmap() {
    Dispose(false);
}

public void Dispose() {
    Dispose(true);
    GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
}

private void Dispose(bool safeDispose) {
    if (_disposing)
        return;

    SaveBits(); // private wrapper to UnlockBits
    bytes = null; // byte[] of the image
    bmpData = null; // BitmapData object

    if (safeDispose && bm != null) {
        bm.Dispose(); // Bitmap object
        bm = null;
    }

    _disposing = true;
}
```

Here's when it works ok:

```
using (var qbm = new QuickBitmap("myfile.jpg"))
{
    // use qbm.GetPixel/qbm.SetPixel at will
}
```

Here's when it doesn't work:

```
public static void Main (string[] args) {
   // this is just an example, simply constructing the object and doing nothing will throw the exception
   var qbm = new QuickBitmap(args[0]);
   qbm.SetPixel(0, 0, Color.Black);
   qbm.Save();
}
```

---

The complete excetion is (there's no inner exception):

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
Additional information: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
```

---

The reproduction is 100%, even on different machines. I do figure out we should use `using` or `Dispose()`, not using it is bad and all that stuff. I just want to know: why does this happen? Why is the memory "protected"? Which kind of access am I violating?

Comment: Just curious... why do you think that `LockBits` is "gimmicky"?

Comment: @EdS. because it requires me to keep using `IntPtr`. I use this class to avoid use `IntPtr` in higher-level classes.

Comment: You're not following the prescribed Dispose pattern.

Comment: Hardly seems like a "gimmick" to me, but ok

Comment: There is a pattern for correctly creating an object that has both a disposer and a finalizer, and this code is really not an example of it. Rule one is **unless you are an expert on the garbage collector, do not write a finalizer**. Once you become an expert on the GC then you will know first, whether or not you need to implement a finalizer, and second, how to do so safely.

Comment: Start by naming your variables for what they mean. Your `_disposing` does not mean "I am disposing", it means "I am already disposed", so call it that. Your `safeDispose` means "I am disposing", so call it that.

Comment: Further reading, to convince you to not write a finalizer: http://ericlippert.com/2013/06/10/construction-destruction/, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20731667/why-is-finalizer-called-on-object/20731890#20731890, http://stackoverflow.com/a/5223583/88656, http://stackoverflow.com/a/13955187/88656

Comment: And http://blog.coverity.com/2014/02/26/resources-vs-exceptions/

Comment: Thanks for all these sources, will read.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem occurs because you included an unnecessary finalizer in your implementation. Code executed from a finalizer *generally* cannot access managed objects safely. It is likely that the call to `SaveBits` results in the use of managed objects in violation of this rule, though you did not include the code for that method.

The best solution would be to simply remove the finalizer from `QuickBitmap`, since the `QuickBitmap` class does not *directly* own unmanaged resources.

Comment: Isn't having a private `Bitmap` directly owning an unmanaged resource?

Comment: No, `Bitmap` is a managed class, not an unmanaged resource. An unmanged resource might be an `IntPtr` created by `Marshal.AllocHGlobal`, which would not be freed by any means other than an explicit call to `Marshal.FreeHGlobal`.

Answer (score 0):

The whole *point* of `IDisposable` is to gracefully clean up unmanaged resources.  The literal *definition* of an unmanaged resource is a resource that the GC won't be able to clean up on its own.  Unsurprisingly, it won't be able to clean it up on its own if you don't.  Objects that can be cleaned up entirely through the GC need not be disposable, and this require no manual disposal.  If the object could be cleaned up without manual disposable then it wouldn't have a need to implement `IDisposable` in the first place.

Comment: This doesn't answer my question at all. I'm well aware of what `IDisposable` and GC mean, what I'm looking for is the difference between calling the `Dipose` manually or from destructor.

Comment: @Mephy You asked if you need to manually dispose of the resource to ensure that it gets disposed.  You do, and that's that.  There would be no need to have an `IDisposable` interface in the first place if it never needed to actually be used.  If you need to actually be sure the cleanup happens for an unmanaged resource, you need to manually dispose of it.  That's all there is to it.